# C# - Reading NewLine characters from reading a string character by character

Tags: c#, visual-studio, switch-statement, character, newline

So I have a program that does a for loop, reading every character one by one and replacing it with a four digit number correlating to that particular letter using a case statement.

My problem is it is not reading NewLine characters ('\n') and I don't know how to fix this.

Here is my code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < inputTextBox.Text.Length; i++)
        {
            //Encryption
            switch (inputTextBox.Text[i])
            {
                // I got rid of the rest of the cases
                // as they are not relevant
                case '\n':
                    encryptedString = encryptedString + "8024";
                    break;
            }
        }
```

and since it does not accept the new line as a character, it doesn't add it to the encryptedString.

This might seem like a duplicate question but the other posts that I found were actually in completely different situations.

EDIT ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
So after debugging, it turns out it is actually reading the '\n' it is just not writing it to the string when decoding it.

here's the code for the decoding section:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < readString.Length; i = i + 4)
            {
            //Decryption
            switch (readString.Substring(i, 4))
            {
                case "8024":
                    decryptedString = decryptedString + "\n";
                    break;
            }
        }
        inputTextBox.Text = decryptedString;
```

So it is reaching the "decryptedString = decryptedString + "\n";" line it is just not adding a new line to the string for some reason. I have also tried '\n' instead of "\n" just to be sure.

Comment: Well, obvious question is...do you have newlines in your textbox (=is it multiline)?! Side note: use a StringBuilder, concatenating strings is terribly inefficient.

Comment: I did a quick test, and it's working for me (i.e. it's hitting that case).  Have you tried debugging?  Does it hit your case for `'\n'`?  I'm voting to close this as off topic for "why is this code not working".

Comment: @roryap I have edited the question now, it's not actually adding the new line to the string, so hopefully you can help.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Yes, it's a multiline textBox and I have experimented with the order of the newlines in relation to the rest of the content. And I'm still a beginner so thanks for the tip, I'll look into using a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I replaced the "\n" when decoding the newlines with a "System.Environment.NewLine" and it fixed the problem.

Comment: Glad that you found it yourself

Answer (score -2):

Try first replace new lines with this `Regex.Replace(inputTextBox.Text, "\r\\D\n?|\n\\D\r?", "\n");`

EDIT: Are you sure it didn't worked?
For examlpe if encryptedstring is:

> First string
>   second
>   3rd
>   fourth

Using this:

```
encryptedString = Regex.Replace(encryptedString, "\r\\D\n?|\n\\D\r?", "\n");
encryptedString = encryptedString.Replace("\n", "8024");
```

Will make encryptedString = `First string8024second80243rd8024fourth` is that what you wanted?